# Flutter Dart Version mismatch

Tags: flutter, dart

I have just upgraded Dart to the latest version 3.0.4

[image: Dart SDK in terminal]

but when I try and run the project that required SDK `sdk: '>=3.0.2 <4.0.0'`, it says my current dart SDK is 3.0.0.

[image]

[image]

Why is the flutter dart SDK not getting the latest version?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your Dart in first picture is not the same as Dart in second picture. In my case, when I type `which dart` in Terminal.app, OS will say: `/opt/homebrew/bin/dart`. But when I type `which dart` in VSCode's Terminal, it says: `/Users/<name>/development/flutter_3_7_8/bin//dart`.

What this thing indicates? Inside your Flutter SDK, it **ALREADY EXISTS** Dart inside. These 2 things are **different**. So if you want to actual upgrade Flutter's things, you need to run `flutter upgrade` & your Flutter will upgrade to 3.10 & Dart will also update to version 3. Things are little complicated, hope you understand :)

Comment: The thing is, I am already using flutter 3.10 and it has dart 3. But now i am trying to upgrade the dart version to 3.0.4 which is the latest one. P.S. i have same dart pah in both terminal and VS Code

Comment: can you run `flutter doctor -v`?

Comment: upgrading the flutter to `3.10.4` upgraded the dart to`3.0.4`. Thanks for the help though

Comment: You do not meet the dart version of the package you are using, so you reduce this error.(infinite_carousel)